# EmberJS: Retransition to current route and reset dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js

I have some routes defined like:

```
Router.map(function() {
      this.route('foo', function() {
         this.route('bar');
         this.route('bar', {path: 'bar/:fooid'});
      });
      // ...
});
```

The dynamic segment in `/foo/bar/:fooid` is an id that can be validated against some rules. To simplify the example, let's assume `:fooid` must consist of exactly 3 digits.

If an invalid value gets passed like in `/foo/bar/1234567`, I want reset the url to `foo/bar/`.

Simplified foo.bar route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model (params) {
     // If fooid is invalid, set model.fooid.isValid to false
  },

  afterModel (model, transition) {
     // If fooid is invalid...
     this.transitionTo('/foo/bar/');
  }

});
```

The validation process itself works but I can't get rid of the wrong `:fooid` parameter in the url!

If I transition to a different route it works fine.

Ember version is 2.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make use of the default index route, which will come for the every route.

```
this.route('foo', function() {
    this.route('bar', function () {        
        this.route('child', { path: ":fooid" });
    });
});
```

Here for the URL `/foo/bar`

```
route- app/routes/foo/bar/index.js  
controller - app/controllers/foo/bar/index.js  
template - app/templates/foo/bar/child.hbs
```

and for the URL `/foo/bar/123`

```
route- app/routes/foo/bar/child.js  
controller - app/controllers/foo/bar/child.js  
template - app/templates/foo/bar/index.hbs
```

If you have the above structure then you can transition from `foo.bar.child` to `foo.bar.index` route.

In model hook of the `app/routes/foo/bar/child.js` you can say `this.transitionTo('foo.bar.index')`. it will take you to that route.

Note:
1.If you defined dynamic segment then you need to provide valid value. otherwise ember will not allow to enter into the route. I am not how `foo/bar/` is worked out for you when you try it directly from the URL.
2.Its good to use the route name for `transitionTo` method instead of direct URL.
2. You can try http://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal/route/post for better understanding of the ember routing model

---

In `beforeModel` hook, you can check the incoming param `fooid`, if its in wrong state, then you can `transitionTo`  with default value.

```
beforeModel(transition){
 // you can transition.params[transition.targetName].fooid to get the value.
 //then try transitionTo the same route with default value
 this.transitionTo('foo.bar',defaultValue)
}
```

Comment: `transition.abort()` and then `transition.retry()` might clear the queryParams . there is open issue regarding this. you can even try that one also.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have an idea which default value I could use? `{fooid: null}` will change url to `/foo/bar/null/` and `{}`or `{fooid: ''}` will cause an error: `You must provide param fooid to generate.`. If I browse manually to `/foo/bar/` everything works fine. How can I do this using `transitionTo`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion..I was talking about queryParam but you are using the dynamic segments.  default value stuff is only suitable for query params.

Comment: Thanks again, that was the input i was looking for.